# Why React render all page (menu, header and so on) every page change (using routing)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React.
I have an app like this:

```
<>
    <Header currentUser={currentUser}></Header>
    <Menu items={menuitems}/>   
    <SubHeader currentUser={currentUser}></SubHeader>
    <Breadcrumb items={crumbs} ></Breadcrumb>
    <BrowserRouter  history={history} > 
            <div >              
                <div className="container-fluid main-container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-2"></div>
                        <div className="col-md-9">
                            <Switch>
                                {routes.map((rou,key) => {
                                return   <PrivateRoute exact 
                                            path={rou.path} 
                                            key={key} 
                                            component={rou.component} 
                                            canAccess={rou.canAccess} 
                                            fallBackComponent={rou.fallBackComponent}/>;
                                })} 
                            </Switch>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-1"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </BrowserRouter >
    <Footer ></Footer>
</>
```

I would expect that every page change (using the Router), React would render only the part between tags , instead, every route change, I see that React reloads all components  outside the router like `<Header>`, `<Menu>` and so on.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you navigating to a route? Are you using the `<Link>` component? Is there anything further up the tree, that depends on the location?

Comment: No, I am not using the Link component. Should I? I thought it would  simply render an <a> tag.

Comment: With an `<a>` tag the browser will just request the page the link points to and bypass any programmatical routing in your javascript. It will not only re-render your components but basically reload the whole page including the react app. You need to use the `Link` component of `react-router` instead. It does more than just rendering an `<a>`. It intercepts the click on it and programmatically sets the new location without a page reload.

Comment: Thank you,you are right, I just fixed and it works.